# In Ember Data how do I set a relationship field by id without it sending null to the server?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an order model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  account: DS.belongsTo('account', {async: true}),
  address: DS.belongsTo('address', {async: true}),
  orderItems: DS.hasMany('orderItem', {async: true}),
  orderStatus: DS.belongsTo('orderStatus', {async: true}),
  specialInstructions: DS.attr('string'),
  creationDate: DS.attr('date')
});
```

This has a order status, which has the model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  value: DS.attr('string'),
  orders: DS.hasMany('order', {async: true})
});
```

In the order/create route I use `model` to get the account and then `afterModel` to create a new order in the db straight away. I want to create it in afterModel like this:

```
var order = this.store.createRecord('order', {
  account: model,
  orderStatus: 1
});

return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  order: order.save().then(function() {
    self.set('order', order);
  }),
  products: this.store.findAll('product').then(function(result) {
    self.set('products', result);
  })
});
```

But looking at the POST to the server Ember is sending orderStatus: null to the server.

In addition to this I want to set it again later in a saveOrder action (on the controller).

```
order.set('orderStatus', 3);
order.save().then(function() {
    self.transitionToRoute('member.orders', order.get('account'));
});
```

Can I do it this way? I also have components that want to send up actions to save objects (looking towards Ember 2.0), where setting id's would be ideal as I won't want to access the store in a component etc.

Comment: As far as I know you can't set relationship by id, only by object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `store.getReference('orderStatus', 3)` to get a reference to the `OrderStatus` and then set it as you would with a model:

```
const orderStatus = store.getReference('orderStatus', 3)
order.set('orderStatus', orderStatus)
```

I know this is an old question, but since I stumbled upon it looking for the answer I thought someone else would do the same!